# How to convert markdown to html that make it more beautiful, colorful with python

Tags: python, html, css, markdown

I want to convert markdown text to html with Python, but when I googled, I only get the result about Markdown library like this:

````
import markdown

md_text = """
```python 
# some Python code
hi = 'Hello'
print(hi)
```
"""
html = markdown.markdown(md_text, extensions=['fenced_code', 'codehilite'])
print(html)
````

It also converts markdown text to html but the css is very bad and has no color, nor code block.

So what can I do to get more beautiful, colorful html from markdown text? Thank all!

Comment: Add your own CSS!

Comment: So it doesn't have any other solution that I can convert it without write CSS code? Beacause I'm bad at FE :<

Comment: The `markdown` package spits out the HTML snippet of the markdown you gave it. At best it adds some classes. Everything else, even the basic HTML structure, is your task.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I finally found a solution here :
https://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter

code = 'print "Hello World"'
print(highlight(code, PythonLexer(), HtmlFormatter()))
```

Enjoy :-)